# for comprehension in scala for implementing flatMap

Tags: scala, for-loop

Prof. Odersky in Coursera course has implemented `flatMap` using for loops as following:

```
def flatMap[T, U](xs: List[T], f: T => Iterable[U]) = for (x <- xs; y <- f(x)) yield y
```

And here's some application on the two functions (result as expected):

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
flatMap[Int, Int](xs, x=> List(x /2))
```

However, When I try implement the flatMap as:

```
for (x <- xs) yield f(x)
```

It does not return the correct answer, it returns a List of Lists (it should return one big list contains all elements of the inner lists)

My question is, What is the different that make `flatMap` works as expected; between both:

```
for (x <- xs; y <- f(x)) yield y
//And
for (x <- xs) yield f(x)
```

And Why `for (x <- xs; y <- x * x) yield y` not compiling?

Comment: Well, `f(x)` returns an (iterable) list. `x * x` doesn't.

Comment: but here: `for (x <- xs) yield x` we yielding a single element by element. what is the different?

Comment: Yes, that would return a `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` for your `xs` - every element is taken out of it and placed in a new list. Try `for (x <- xs) yield x * x`

Comment: A for comprehension, though it looks a little like a loop, is not a loop. It is converted to a sequence of higher order function calls by the compiler. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html might help with understanding.

Comment: Aha,  this is because, `f(x)` here returns a list which have the 3 basic functions required for a for comprehension to work, `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` (Duck Typing), and if f(x) returns say `Int`, I would get compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second version doesn't involve a call to flatMap at all. You can use reify to de-sugar the for comprehension and see:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val f: Int => Iterable[Int] = null
f: Int => Iterable[Int] = null

scala> val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> reify { for (x <- xs; y <- f(x)) yield y }
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[Int]] = Expr[List[Int]]($read.xs.flatMap(((x) => $read.f.apply(x).map(((y) => y))(Iterable.canBuildFrom)))(List.canBuildFrom))

scala> reify { for (x <- xs) yield f(x) }
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[Iterable[Int]]] = Expr[List[scala.Iterable[Int]]]($read.xs.map(((x) => $read.f.apply(x)))(List.canBuildFrom))
```

the first can be simplified to:

```
xs.flatMap(x => f(x).map(identity))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
xs.flatMap(f)
```

and the second can be simplified to:

```
xs.map(f)
```

Comment: Aha, a simple answer would be: a `for comprehension` with 1 generator always mapped to a `map`, while a one with >1 generator involves `flatMap`

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy the number doesn't matter, its that the last thing results in map instead of flatMap, no matter if there are 1 or if there are many

Comment: This what I understood from https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/progfun/lecture_slides/week6-5.pdf